# CSAPP Attack Lab Phase1 Segmentation Fault on Ubuntu22.04

Tags: ubuntu, segmentation-fault

I'm a beginner recently working on CSAPP attack lab on Ubuntu22.04.
I download the files and run ctarget in terminal,

```bash
./ctarget
```

Typically, CTARGET is expected to receive stdin as code injection , and injecting too much characters leads to segmentation fault .
However, without typing anything , the program terminates suddenly with :

```bash
Ouch!: You caused a segmentation fault!
Better luck next time
FAILED
```

I tried to use GDB to checkout what's wrong , I checked the stack frame when it terminated:

```bash
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7c750d0 in __vfprintf_internal (
    s=0x7ffff7e1a780 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, 
    format=format@entry=0x4044bc "Type string:", ap=ap@entry=0x556311b8, 
    mode_flags=mode_flags@entry=0)
    at ./stdio-common/vfprintf-internal.c:1244
#1  0x00007ffff7c6079f in __printf (
    format=format@entry=0x4044bc "Type string:")
    at ./stdio-common/printf.c:33
#2  0x00000000004022c3 in launch (offset=<optimized out>)
    at support.c:293
#3  0x000000000040233d in stable_launch (offset=<optimized out>)
    at support.c:340
```

But there's no more I can do to cope with it .o(╥﹏╥)o
Is it possible due to ubuntu system? Will it work if I switch to other Linux distros?

Thanks a lot for answering my question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself! It turns out that the reason it was failing was due to the operating system that I selected. None of the Ubuntu versions that I tried (`20.04`, `21.03`, `21.10`, and `22.04`) worked; however, `Fedora 39` allowed it to run properly. This leads me to suspect that the `ctarget` application was specifically built to run on Fedora, or perhaps requires specific dependencies or dependency versions that the Ubuntu operating systems I downloaded did not have.

Comment: I am using Windows 10, I tried using WSL2 and the Ubuntu default system, haven't worked. But, using Debian, the second one in the WSL2 list (`wsl --list --online`), it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. And my resolution is as follows:

### Reason for segmentation fault

Using gdb, I found that it is a `movaps %xmm1, 0x10(%rsp)` instruction in my glibc that causes the failure. I guess that the align requirement of `movaps` is not satisfied, because the glibc version when compiling the `ctarget` is so old that the requirement that the size of each frame shall be a multiple of 16 have not been standard. Then I force the `rsp` to be a multiple of 16 before the program enters `__printf_chk@plt` in gdb, and it works out and confirm my reasoning.

### Use LD_PRELOAD to force the alignment of `rsp`

A resolution is that we can add an abstraction layer, providing a adaptive printf interface.

First of all, we write such code in `printf.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int __printf_chk(int flag, const char *fmt, ...) {
  va_list ap;
  int ret;
  va_start(ap, fmt);
  ret = vfprintf(stdout, fmt, ap);
  va_end(ap);
  return ret;
}
```

Then compile it to get `printf.s`:

```bash
$ gcc -shared -fPIC -S printf.c -O2
```

After that, we modify the `printf.s` file to ensure the low 4 bit of `rsp` be `1000B`:

```
--- printf_old.s    2024-01-17 21:03:58.615062917 +0800
+++ printf.s    2024-01-17 21:00:24.983879497 +0800
@@ -7,6 +7,10 @@
 .LFB23:
    .cfi_startproc
    endbr64
+  pushq %rbp
+  movq  %rsp, %rbp
+  andq  $-0x10, %rsp
+  subq  $-0x8, %rsp
    subq    $216, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 224
    movq    %rsi, %r10
@@ -44,6 +48,7 @@
    subq    %fs:40, %rdx
    jne .L6
    addq    $216, %rsp
+  leave
    .cfi_remember_state
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
```

and get the final `printf.so`:

```bash
$ gcc -shared -fPIC -o printf.so printf.s
```

Finally, use `LD_PRELOAD` to replace the `__printf_chk` provided in glibc with ours:

```bash
$ LD_PRELOAD=./printf.so ./ctarget -q
```

and it works.

Comment: In fact, using a naive implementation of `printf` family is even a better choice.

Comment: I provide an alternative method in https://blog.rijuyuezhu.top/posts/db646f34/